# Strange Permissions Error with Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: permissions

I have a folder created in /opt called softwares where I wanted to install and additional softwares that I want to use. Here is the contents:

```
joesan@joesan-InfinityBook-S-14-v5:/opt/softwares$ sudo ls -la
total 28
drwxr-xr-x 7 joesan joesan 4096 Jul 17 19:24 .
drwxr-xr-x 7 root   root   4096 Jul 17 21:45 ..
drwxrwxr-x 6 joesan joesan 4096 Jul 17 18:49 apache-maven-3.6.3
drwxrwxr-x 8 joesan joesan 4096 Jul 17 18:50 idea-IC-201.8538.31
drwxr-xr-x 6 joesan joesan 4096 Jul 17 19:24 rustup
drwxrwxr-x 4 joesan joesan 4096 Jun 28 00:07 sbt
drwxrwxr-x 6 joesan joesan 4096 Jun 25 22:59 scala-2.13.3
joesan@joesan-InfinityBook-S-14-v5:/opt/softwares$
```

As you can see that the contents inside this folder belongs to my user joesan, but why is the .. folder still belonging to the root. How can I change it?

Additionally, I'm facing this error:

```
joesan@joesan-InfinityBook-S-14-v5:~$ cd /opt/softwares/
cannot access '.': Permission denied (os error 13)
joesan@joesan-InfinityBook-S-14-v5:/opt/softwares$ ls
```

Any ideas why this error occurs?

Comment: `drwxr-xr-x 7 root   root   4096 Jul 17 21:45 ..` means that `/opt` belongs to root. That is normal.

Comment: agreed that the first question is normal behavior... the second question: I can't seem to duplicate it playing with opt's permissions. Is there something else governing the permissions of that directory? Is it a mount point? Is there something else you configured that sets permissions on those directories? Did you mess with setfacl or selinux??? just curious what's the output of `namei -m /opt/softwares/`  ....also `ls -laZ /`